# Xcode Framework: Umbrella header for module 'Test' does not include header 'NewTest.h'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctest

```
framework module Test {
  umbrella header "Test.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

This is what my module file looks like. How can I resolve the following warning.

> Umbrella header for module 'Test' does not include header 'NewTest.h'

I am not familiar with module files.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a module map

modify the code to-

```
 framework module Test {
      umbrella header "Test.h"

      export *
      module * { export * }

 explicit module BFAppLinkResolving {
    header "BFAppLinkResolving.h"
    link "BFAppLinkResolving"
    export *
  }

  explicit module BFWebViewAppLinkResolver {
      header "BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.h"
      link "BFAWebViewAppLinkResolver"
      export *
  }
    }
```