# Swift module umbrella header warning for 'MyClass+BackdoorExtension.h'

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, module, frameworks

When I compile my framework into an iOS app project, I continually get these linker warnings:

```
<module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'MyFramework' does not include header 'MyClass+BackdoorExtension.h'
```

```
…/AppProject/AppClass.m:123:456 warning: missing submodule MyFramework.MyClass_BackdoorExtension' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
#import <MyFramework/MyClass+BackdoorExtension.h>
```

However, unlike these SO answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768743/xcode-framework-umbrella-header-for-module-test-does-not-include-header-newt), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508434/xcode-llvm-7-0-disable-warning-umbrella-header-for-module-does-not-include-he), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923483/umbrella-header-for-module-myframework-does-not-include-header-otherframework); I don't want `MyClass+BackdoorExtension.h` to be lumped in with all the other headers for the framework.  `MyClass+BackdoorExtension.h` is a hidden “back door” interface for my framework's `MyClass`— ***usage of the `BackdoorExtension`'s member should produce a `error: property 'backdoorMember' not found on object of type 'MyClass *'` unless that specific app source file includes `MyClass+BackdoorExtension.h`***.

Prior to Swift modules, this would work as expected without giving linker warnings; `backdoorMember` was inaccessible unless the app's `.m` file had a `#import <MyFramework/MyClass+BackdoorExtension.h>`, after the addition of which everything compiled and ran without warnings or runtime issues.  As it stands, everything compiles & runs as expected, but I'd like to squelch the warning *(I'm the type of dev who likes to treat warnings as must-fix errors)*.  And I'd like to find a way to make this work using the existing aforementioned `#import` in app Objective-C files and an equivalent import in app Swift files too *(e.g. `import MyFramework.MyClass+BackdoorExtension`)*.

I've experimented with `explicit module`s & `explicit header`s in my framework's `module.modulemap` to no avail.

---

Here's my current framework `module.modulemap`:

```
module MyFramework {
    umbrella header "MyFramework.h"
    export *
}
```

and framework umbrella header `MyFramework.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <MyFramework/BaseClass.h>
#import <MyFramework/MyClass.h>
#import <MyFramework/AnotherClass.h>
```

And here's the framework's `MyClass+BackdoorExtension.h` (which has Public Target Membership for the framework):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass (BackdoorExtension)

@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL backdoorMember;

@end
```

I'm using Xcode 8.1 with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1).

Comment: I had a typo in my answer. Updated.